# Django UserCreationForm raise Validation Error when email already exist

Tags: django

Hi there I am new to Django. 
I have got a UserRegisterForm inherited from UserCreationForm. 
Everything works fine

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]
```

Now I want the to show a sign 'email already exist' near by the email input box if the email's already in the database. 
I have tried:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]

    def clean_email(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Username is not unique")
        return username

    def clean_username(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email is not unique")
        return email
```

It didn't work.
I will be so glad if anyone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch the two method names:

```
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Username is not unique")
    return username

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email is not unique")
    return email
```